# Retrieving a single cell value from a datagrid in Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, adobe, flexbuilder, flex3

I'm using CF to retrieve values from a database that are then being stored in a datagrid in Flex. I then want to selectively take the value from one cell of the datagrid and store it as a string variable. I've searched around, but I haven't been able to come about a solution. The users will not be interacting at all with the datagrid as it will be hidden to them. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you bothering to use a DataGrid if it is *hidden* to the user? Store your data in an ArrayCollection of objects or in an XML document and access that. Loading up a heavyweight user control just to be invisible is unnecessary processing time and wasted development time. In any case, the way you get chunks out of a DataGrid or AdvancedDataGrid is to access its dataProvider and manipulate *that*. Just eliminate the "middle man" here and you should be fine.