# Get content of a single cell from a DataGrid in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, select, datagrid, flex3, dataprovider

I want to select information in a single cell from my DataGrid in Flex 3.

Specifically, I'm displaying three phone numbers per line and the user needs to be able to select one of those numbers, from any row, but not the whole row.

While similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423130/retrieving-a-single-cell-value-from-a-datagrid-in-adobe-flex), I am displaying the DataGrid to the user. The answer for that question was to manipulate the dataProvider, how can I know what cell I've selected in order to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://siphu.wordpress.com/2009/08/26/get-selected-cell-value-of-datagrid-in-flex/).

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with the value returned from the labelFunction?

Comment: Would label.text work? Haven't tried it but it makes sense to me ^__^
Regards