# Get content of a single cells labelFunction from a DataGrid in Flex 3

Tags: datagrid, flex3, labelfunction

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476476/get-content-of-a-single-cell-from-a-datagrid-in-flex-3) I asked last week.

My dataGrid is populated with three phone numbers per row. Each phone number is pulled from an array and displayed using a labelFunction, while the name and description come from the dataProvider. I used the really helpful solution to my last question with some success, but can't grab the actual data.

Maybe I've spent too much time on it but I'm stumped and stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the specific data using the code below, thanks to help from a collegue:

```
var x:DataGridItemRenderer = event.itemRenderer as DataGridItemRenderer;
var y:DataGridListData = x.listData as DataGridListData;
var z:String = y.label;
```

I hope this helps someone.